What font was used here? (Apple Watch font)

Hello, I was wondering what font was used on this Apple watch face? Thanks for your help.

It's the Nike Globe font. It's not yet distributed, it's a custom design made by Chul Lee for Nike.
You can find all the numbers here :
https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/v2/D5622AQEgZBi2eTSynw/feedshare-shrink_800/feedshare-shrink_800/0/1717140243196?e=2147483647&v=beta&t=BHAfI_9sVu47JY2lpOXbX0rHcOtJik_--2Nj_NvBNj8
The only way to get it would be to hack the watchOS to get it.
